# Create a dynamic table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Which is the best way to create dynamic tables from scratch in jQuery and then populate them with data.

**EDIT :**

Assume data comes from a script service and I need to create a table dynamically and populate them with the incoming values

Comment: Show us the code that you've tried and describe how it fails to meet your requirements and you might get a few more responses than votes for closure of your question.

Comment: What format is the data returned in? JSON?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways to accomplish the actual creation of the table without plugins. For example:

```
$('body').append('<table id="myTable"></table>');
```

You can then use `.append` to append table headers and rows by calling the table's id. Using `.html` will allow you to populate the table.

Answer (score 2):

[DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) is a feature-rich jQuery Table plugin. Without knowing the functionality required by your application, it's hard to make perfect recommendations, though.

Answer (score 1):

There is nice short introcution to what you are looking for in here: [Creating Dynamic Tables with jQuery](http://hippieitgeek.blogspot.se/2013/01/creating-dynamic-tables-with-jquery.html)

Comment: Would you birefly explain the solution, rather than just linking it?

Answer (score 0):

Writing in a closure to avoid global variables. You can move the code out of the closure (first and last lines) when you put it into your app.

Assigning the table to a variable helps since you've got a resource to manipulate later, instead of requerying which can be taxing. `myTable` is a jQuery object, hence the example `html()` call, that'll add `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags to your table element.

Also note that when you manipulate any element's inner contents, it's always best to wrap all your content inside as few elements as possible, since it will increase manipulation speed.

```
(function() {
   var myTable = $('<table></table>');
   $('body').append(myTable);
   myTable.html('<thead></thead><tbody></tbody>');
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jTemplates](http://jtemplates.tpython.com/) or [DOM creation plugin](http://mg.to/2006/02/27/easy-dom-creation-for-jquery-and-prototype) to write easy to read code.